# How to update strings that are generated by a converter when I change language?

Tags: c#, wpf, multilingual, ivalueconverter

I have a WPF application in which I support multiple langauges. I can change the language runtime, as I load different sets of resource dictionaries containing the string resources upon change of language.

```
private void UpdateLoadedLanguages(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            RemoveLoadedLanguages();

            ResourceDictionary aResourceDictionary = new ResourceDictionary();
            ResourceDictionary bResourceDictionary = new ResourceDictionary();
            ResourceDictionary cLanguageResourceDictionary = new ResourceDictionary();

            Language selectedLanguage = (Language) e.AddedItems[0];

            switch (selectedLanguage)
            {
                case Language.enUS:
                    a.Source = new Uri("pack://application:,,,/[Projecta];component/src/Helpers/Language.en-US.xaml");
                    b.Source = new Uri("pack://application:,,,/[Projectb];component/src/resources/Language.en-US.xaml");
                    c.Source = new Uri("pack://application:,,,/[Projectc];component/src/resources/Language.en-US.xaml");
                    break;
                case Language.nlNL:
                    a.Source = new Uri("pack://application:,,,/[Projecta];component/src/Helpers/Language.nl-NL.xaml");
                    b.Source = new Uri("pack://application:,,,/[Projectb];component/src/resources/Language.nl-NL.xaml");
                    c.Source = new Uri("pack://application:,,,/[Projectc];component/src/resources/Language.nl-NL.xaml");
                    break;
                default:
                    a.Source = new Uri("pack://application:,,,/[Projecta];component/src/Helpers/Language.en-US.xaml");
                    b.Source = new Uri("pack://application:,,,/[Projectb];component/src/resources/Language.en-US.xaml");
                    c.Source = new Uri("pack://application:,,,/[Projectc];component/src/resources/Language.en-US.xaml");
                    break;
            }

            App.Current.Resources.MergedDictionaries.Add(aResourceDictionary );
            App.Current.Resources.MergedDictionaries.Add(bResourceDictionary );
            App.Current.Resources.MergedDictionaries.Add(cResourceDictionary );
        }
```

A resource dictionary with the translations typically looks like this:

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                    xmlns:system="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib">

    <system:String x:Key="DefaultApplicationTitleString">Title</system:String>
    <system:String x:Key="DefaultDoneString">Done</system:String>
    <system:String x:Key="DefaultCancelString">Cancel</system:String>
    <system:String x:Key="DefaultDescriptionString">Description unknown</system:String>

    <system:String x:Key="LanguageSelectionString">Language</system:String>
    <system:String x:Key="AisleString">Aisle</system:String>
    <system:String x:Key="LevelsString">levels</system:String>

</ResourceDictionary>
```

When I use one of the strings as defined above like directly below it works perfect.

```
Title="{DynamicResource DefaultApplicationTitleString}"
```

But with a converter like this ...

```
public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            string text = (string) Application.Current.FindResource("DefaultDescriptionString");

            if (value != null)
            {
                string temp = (string) value;

                char[] stringSeparators = { 'A', '.', '-' };
                string[] stringElements= temp.Split(stringSeparators, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

                string aisleString = (string) Application.Current.FindResource("AisleString");
                string levelsString = (string) Application.Current.FindResource("LevelsString");

                text = aisleString + " " + stringElements[1] + ", " + levelsString + " " + stringElements[2] + " - " +
                               stringElements[3];

            }

            return text;
        }
```

... that I use like this ...

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Id, Converter={StaticResource ItemIdToTextConverter}}" />
```

... then my strings aren't updated when I change the language. If the property that I convert is updated on its viewModel then the language change does happen.

So my question: **Does anyone have a solution for me where also my strings as a result of converters are updated on a language change?**

My guesses for a solution are:

1. force an update of all frameworkelements that use a resource (How would I do this?)
2. or maybe do something with DynamicResourceExtenstion (I found this question: [Return a dynamic resource from a converter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7609979/return-a-dynamic-resource-from-a-converter), however I do not understand the explanation of the DynamicResourceExtension. So is this the way to go? If so, how would I implement this?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This would be too much for a comment, but to little for an answer (or maybe not).

Converter is called only once when element is initializing. After that there is no *link* to what was the source if you are using `StaticResource`. If you use `DynamicResource`, then anytime when *source* get changed converter will be called again.

- Do you change source in your localization approach? Nope.
- Does converter gets invoked when language is changed? Yes, but only on notification from `Id` (`PropertyChanged`).

One way you can fix it is to subscribe your ViewModel to language switch event and call property changed event *for each property*. This will execute your converter despite source values still the same.

Other possibility would be to *register* somehow objects which required localized data. You will not use converter anymore, but an attached property (or behavior, depends on complexity). Enumerating (or keeping a list) over elements with such property and updating it shouldn't be hard.

Third way (which I am going to use in my very first localized wpf application) is reflection. Register all windows upong creation (un-register when unloading of course), define a schema of how you identify localizable properties of elements and go through it - win.

Regarding schema. My "localizable" controls with *static* content will be using already existing `Uid` to define a *key*, instead of defining things in separate resource dictionary it will be automatically generated). *Dynamic* ones I don't yet decide, perhaps there will be a behavior or attached property or even small peace of code behind (I like MVVM, but I am not making it an absolute) to reassign values from static class with predefined strings, which will be changed by reflection.

Comment: Thank you for your reply! I took inspiration out of your first way to solve the problem, call property changed event. So I extended my base class for viewmodels with a method that raises the property changed events for all properties relevant to that one viewModel. On change of language selection I call that method for all loaded viewModels.